# Difference between file size and string bytelength of text file content?

Tags: tcl

I'm experimenting with coding a very small application-specific local server in Tcl and don't understand the proper method of determining `Content-length`.  I read that it is bytes or decimal number of octets.

In the code below, `[file size "index.html"]` returns the correct length such that the browser read/loads all of the content; but `[string bytelength $html]` is too small and the browser does not read to the end.

Why is this and is there a better method?  Thank you.

```
if { $op eq "GET" } {
  if { $arg eq "/" } {
    set fp [open "index.html" r]
    set html [read $fp]
    set resp "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
    append resp "Connection: Keep-Alive\n"
    append resp "Content-Type: text/html; charset: utf-8\n"
    append resp "Content-length: [file size "index.html"]\n\n"
    #append resp "Content-length: [string bytelength $html]\n\n"
    append resp $html
    puts stdout $resp
    puts $so $resp
    close $fp
    unset html resp
  }
  # Remainder of if $arg
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `file size` is the number of bytes that the file takes up on disk, and is exactly the number reported by the OS. (It's also the offset you'd be at if you opened the file and `seek`ed to the end.)

If you were to read the file in *in binary mode,* the `string length` of what you read would be the same as the `file size`. When the file is read in (default) text mode it's different because it depends on the encoding that the file is read with; encodings like UTF-8 can use multiple bytes to describe a character and `string length` reports the number of characters in a string.

The `string bytelength` command reports the number of bytes used by the data when it is encoded using Tcl's internal encoding (which is rather similar to UTF-8 but not exactly; there are specific denormalizations). That encoding is not normally exposed to the outside world, and is only really of interest to C extensions. Of course, those C extensions can get the length of a string for themselves easily anyway: it's produced (as an OUT parameter because the string itself is the return value) by `Tcl_GetStringFromObj()` so `string bytelength` isn't very useful. Indeed, **I've only ever found *one* (1) legitimate use for it,** and a better job of integration work with that extension would have got rid of it.

The value reported by `string bytelength` is *not* the amount of storage currently used by a value, but rather just (closely related to, by a static difference) the amount of storage used by the standard “string” interpretation. If the value has any other (“internal”) representation as well, which is common (numbers, binary data, true-unicode data, lists, dictionaries, command names, channel handlers, executable code, all those may have additional representation data) then that is *not* counted.

In your case, you want to open the file in *binary* mode and use that. And also do this:

```
set filename "index.html"
set fp [open $filename rb];   # NB: rb — b is for BINARY; this is important
set size [file size $filename]

# HTTP spec says headers are ISO 8859-1 and CRLF-separated
fconfigure $so -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
set headers ""
append headers "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
append headers "Connection: Keep-Alive\n"
# Detecting the content type of a file is its own chunk of complexity
append headers "Content-Type: text/html; charset: utf-8\n"
append headers "Content-length: $size\n"
puts stdout $headers
puts $so $headers

# Ship the data in binary mode; fcopy is VERY efficient
fconfigure $so -translation binary
fcopy $fp $so -size $size
close $fp
```

Writing HTTP messages to the console is a bit messy because of the mixed encoding used; it's not normally a good idea to write the body of a file. But for debugging you would do:

```
set data [read $fp]
puts stdout $data
# Additional -nonewline to not add a line terminator
puts -nonewline $so $data
```

However, the `fcopy` command (also called `chan copy` in newer Tcl as part of a command systematization effort) is much more efficient when moving binary data from one place to another. The only way we could make it significantly more efficient would be to move the copy into the OS kernel.

---

**tl;dr:** You don't want to use `string bytelength`. What it does is subtly not useful.

Comment: With HTTP serving, you _definitely_ want to handle file content as binary unless you need to.

Comment: The subtleties of Tcl's internal encoding relate to how both NUL and characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane are handled, where both are denormalized in order to enable other parts of Tcl to be more efficient. But you're never supposed to use that with the outside world; the `identity` encoding is deprecated for really good reasons (and is even worse on input).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and code sample. Both are extremely helpful.  I've been comparing two texts on Tcl and the Entice PDF in attempt to learn a bunch in a hurry, and, likely, too quickly for my own good.